# Loop through unknown amount of spans - JavaScript MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have these functions:

```
$(".Read-Showing-Comment-Cancel").live('click', function (e) {
  var guid = $(this).data("guid");
  e.preventDefault();

  var f = $('#comments-form-' + guid).slideUp();
  $('comments-text-' + guid).empty();
  $('comments-text-' + guid).value = "";
  $(this).find('.comments-form-' + guid).hide();
  $('comments-sendlink-' + guid).show();
});

$('.showComments').unbind('click').click(function (event) {
  $('.ListingDisplayOptions').hide();

  $(this).find('.comments-form-' + showGuid).show();

  var showGuid = $(this).attr('rel');
  loadShowingsComments(showGuid);
  $(this).attr('id', 'comments-sendlink-' + showGuid);

  event.preventDefault();
});

function loadShowingsComments(guid) {
  var commentTextArea = "#comments-form-" + guid;
  var commentDisplay = ".spanComments" + guid;
  var curComment = $(commentDisplay).text();
  var element = "#comments-form-" + guid;
  $(element).slideDown();
}

<script>
  function showComments() {
    var comments = document.querySelectorAll(".spanComments");
    for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
      comments[i].innerHTML = "This is comment #" + i;
    }
  }
</script>

<a href="#" rel="@currentShowing.ShowingGUID" class="showComments noprint" id="comments-sendlink">View Comments</a>
```

Those functions should grab the information from my controller (it's hooked up correctly.  I've stepped through that and it has populated the right information) and place them in my span:

```
<tr class="p_la" id="comments-form-@currentShowing.ShowingGUID" style="display:none;">
  <td colspan="4" style="border-right:5px solid #DDDDDD;">
    <form action="" method="post">
      <span class="spanComments" cols="100" rows="5">@string.Format("{0} / {1}", @currentShowing.Comments.DateAdded, @currentShowing.Comments.CommentsValue)</span>
      <br />
      <a href="#" class="button red Read-Showing-Comment-Cancel" data-guid="@currentShowing.ShowingGUID" rel="@currentShowing.ShowingGUID" id="comments-cancel-@currentShowing.ShowingGUID">Close</a>
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Unfortunately, when I click on my hyperlink, it only populates the first span with the first span's information.  Works great for the first span but when you click on the hyperlink in the second, third, fourth, etc item, they will only open up the first span with the first span's information.

The code should populate each successive `span` with its own information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My JQuery was off.  It needed this to be changed:

```
$(".Read-Showing-Comment-Cancel").live('click', function (e) {
  var guid = $(this).data("guid");
  e.preventDefault();

  var f = $('#comments-form-' + guid).slideUp();
  $('comments-text-' + guid).empty();
  $('comments-text-' + guid).value = "";
  $(this).parent("form").parent("td").parent("tr").hide();
  $('comments-sendlink-' + guid).show();
});

$('.showComments').unbind('click').click(function (event) {
  $('.ListingDisplayOptions').hide();
  var showGuid = $(this).attr('rel');
  $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").next('#comments-form-' + showGuid).show();
  $(this).attr('id', 'comments-sendlink-' + showGuid);

  event.preventDefault();
});
```